# How to sort a variable in a separate method

Tags: c#, sorting

I currently have this set up to display credit card inputs and outputs:

```
    static void ViewReport(ArrayList paymentReport) //Displays the current payments in a list
    {
        //Activated if the user hits the v or V key
        Console.WriteLine("\n{0,-5}{1,-25}{2,-15}{3,-15}{4,-15}", "Plan", "Number", "Balance", "Payment", "APR");

        foreach (PaymentPlan creditCard in paymentReport)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-5}{1,-25}{2,-15}{3,-15}{4,-15}",
                creditCard.PlanNumber,
                creditCard.CardNumber,
                creditCard.CreditBalance,
                creditCard.MonthlyPayment,
                creditCard.AnnualRate);
        }
    }
```

I have to create a separate method that needs to sort `creditCard.CreditBalance` from lowest to highest. So which would be the best way the sort the list by `creditCard.CreditBalance`which would then reflect the `ViewReport`the next time the user opens it again?

Comment: Why are you using a `ArrayList` that is a legacy type from .NET 1.0? You really, really, should be using generics like `List<PaymentPlan>`. There is almost no reason to use `ArrayList` in new development, the only thing I can think of is working with a library that was written with `ArrayList` (Which is going to either be a very very rare occurrence)

Comment: Actually I was using List<PaymentPlan> before, but the project requirements wants ArrayList instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach (PaymentPlan creditCard in paymentReport.Cast<PaymentPlan>().OrderBy(o=>o.CreditBalance))
```

To change order permanently assign result to your variable:

```
paymentReport = paymentReport.Cast<PaymentPlan>().OrderBy(o=>o.CreditBalance).ToArray();
```

Comment: Note, that this does not modify the order of `paymentReport` just the order this `foreach` will process the items in the list. (from the OP's description it looks like he is expecting a solution that permanently changes the order)

Comment: Epic and fast. Nice one `+one` :)

Comment: That would be correct, it needs to permanently change the order.